# What is the proper way to pass a large amount of memory to a constructor for a class?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, vector, parameter-passing

Please consider these two classes for this example.

The first class defines a simple class with a single public member.

```
class Tester
{
public:
    int m_tester_value;    

    Tester(){}

    Tester(int test_val)
    {
      m_tester_value = test_val;
    } 
    
    Tester(const Tester & data) : m_tester_value(data.m_tester_value)
    {
      std::cout << "Tester Copied!" << std::endl;
    }

    Tester& operator=(const Tester & data)
    {        
       m_tester_value = data.m_tester_value;

      return *this;
    }
};
```

The second class also defines a simple class with a single public member, but this member is a vector of objects from the first `Tester` class.

```
class VectorTester
{
  public:
    std::vector<Tester> m_vector;

  VectorTester(std::vector<Tester>* vector_construct)
  {
    if(vector_construct != nullptr)
    {
      m_vector = *vector_construct;
    }
  }

  VectorTester(const VectorTester & data) :       
                m_vector(data.m_vector)
  {
    std::cout << "VectorTester Copied!" << std::endl;
  }
      
};
```

I believe I am trying to make a copy of the vector within the `VectorTester` class.

I have written a simple function which will generate a `vector<Tester>` for me.

```
std::vector<Tester> TesterVectorGenerator(void)
{
  std::vector<Tester> ret_vector;
  ret_vector.reserve(2);

  ret_vector.emplace_back(65);
  ret_vector.emplace_back(75);

  return ret_vector;
}
```

To test this code, I am using this example.

```
int main() {
  std::vector<Tester> my_test_vector = TesterVectorGenerator();

  VectorTester vector_test = VectorTester(&my_test_vector);
    
  for (const auto &i : vector_test.m_vector)
  {
     // access by value, the type of i is int
     std::cout << "VectorTester.m_vector:" << i.m_tester_value << std::endl;
  }

  for (const auto &i : my_test_vector)
  {
     // access by value, the type of i is int
     std::cout << "my_test_vector:" << i.m_tester_value << std::endl;
  }  
}
```

It all appears to work as intended, the output appears like this:

```
Tester Copied!
Tester Copied!
VectorTester.m_vector:65
VectorTester.m_vector:75
my_test_vector:65
my_test_vector:75
```

**Question 1:** Is this the best way in which to pass a large amount of data into a class? Since a pointer is only 4 bytes of memory, I would think it would be better than passing the entire value into the class and copying it that way.

**Question 2:** Are there any standard idioms for this practice of passing data around for C++?

Thank you for any responses and input on not only the questions, but the code at hand. I am relatively new to C++ and I appreciate any help!

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question, with both constructors you are copying the vector. Not anything wrong with that so long as that is your intent. C++ also has the concept of moving, which will be less expensive than copying a vector, but renders the source vector (vector being moved) unusable.

Comment: One of the constructors is the copy constructor, the other is the normal constructor for the class. I am curious if there is a better way to pass in a large amount of data. Say for example that it is not a vector, but a large object that I need as a member of my class. How should I be passing that information to my class?

Comment: Comes down to the same thing: Is the source movable and expendable? If the class must hold a copy of X, then you have to copy or move that X. Maybe you can get elision working for you, but not if the source could be null.

Comment: Entirely depends on whether or not your class needs its own copy of the dataset or not. If it does, then there's no getting around copying it. If it doesn't, you can pass in a pointer or reference to it, understanding that bad things will happen if the object referred to goes away. Can also move it as mentioned already, understanding the implications for the source.

Comment: In this instance, I would want to ensure that even if the variable passed in no longer exists in memory, that the instance inside the class does. Due to this, I believe a copy is necessary. So, would this be considered the best practice in copying the data then?

Comment: Nothing makes sure that an object will outlive its data quite as well as owning the data. In  some cases shared ownership is useful, though. With a `std::shared_ptr`, the last object to leave turns off the lights.

Answer (score 1):

## Question 1

The copy constructor is just as efficient as the paramaritized pointer constructor (i.e `VectorTester(std::vector<Tester>* vector_construct)`) but is safer as a reference cannot be a `nullptr`. After compilation, references ***might*** just become pointers to the compiler (see: [https://www.godbolt.org/z/qsWdr4qTc]). Therefore, if you wish to copy all the resources from one object/type/class to another, use the copy constructor as it is safer and just as fast as the pointer version. As for the efficiency of the copy of the objects resources, that is up to how you go about that copying. In your case, using [`std::vectors` copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (like you already have) is probably most efficient.

## Question 2

In C++ there are a few types of constructors, most notably the default, copy and move constructors. There are specific semantics that are used to specify which constructor is which.

1. Default - Initializes a object and it's resources into a default state.
2. Copy - Copies the the state of the other object and copies the data from it's resources to the new object.
3. Move - Clones the state of the other object and moves ownership of it's resources to the new object rendering the other object in either an unspecified state of default state.
4. Parametrized Constructor - Uses explicit parameters to initialize the object (eg. a size constructor for reserving memory for a data structure kind).
5. Initializer List Constructor - Uses `std::initializer_list` to initialize the object.

Here is an example class with the first three constructor signatures implemented, these pertain the most to your question.

```cpp
class A
{
private:
    int i;

public:

    /// Default Constructor
    A()
    : i(0) {};

    /// Copy Constructor
    A(const A& a)
    : i(a.i) {};

    /// Move Constructor
    A(A&& a)
    : i(a.i)
    { a.i = 0; };  ///< Leaves `a` in default state
};
```

The signatures in the example above are the most idiomatic in C++ way to specify the default, copy and move constructors in C++. See it in action [here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/xo8rs1zbK).